# On dit « Il a changé la télévision de place », pourrait-on dire « Il a changé la télévision de mur »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Contexte:

Il est question du réaménagement d’un loft. Au lieu de dire « Il a changé la télévision de place; il l’a mise devant un autre mur », pourrait-on, dans un souci de concision, dire « Il a changé la télévision de mur »?

Edit: langage parlé.

Comment: https://www.maison-travaux.fr/maison-travaux/conseils-pratiques/salon-15-coins-tv-super-canons-213868.html#item=1 installer une télévision//changer le mur d'installation ou d'emplacement de la télé. Svp, nous indiquer: langage parlé, écrit, formel, technique, etc. Merci.

Comment: les télévisions sont fixées ou accrochées au mur. https://www.elle.fr/Deco/Pratique/Amenagement/Tous-nos-conseils-pour-bien-installer-votre-TV

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Toutes sortes d'énonciations dont les associations sont généralement vagues peuvent être faites en des circonstances particulières où elles prennent un sens. Une énonciation telle que celle-ci est sans problème dans une salle polyvalente ou autre quand on sait, ou qu'on peut apprendre, que se trouve dans la salle au moins un système prévu pour recevoir une télévision, ce système étant accroché à un mur. Autrement et dans le cas d'un réaménagement, il reste encore à savoir de quelle ampleur est celui-ci ; on est tout aussi bien sensé comprendre qu'une prise coaxiale a été placée sur un autre mur. Dans ce cas où « télévision » est compris métonymiquement comme signifiant une telle prise, il n'y a aucun problème, ce genre de formulation est courant ; toutefois, lorsqu'il s'agit de l'appareil avec sa propre table, le terme consacré est « coin » (place, endroit)  ou « côté » plutôt que « mur », apparemment parce qu'il n'y a pas d'association naturelle de ces appareils avec un mur.

- Il a changé la télévision de côté.

Ce serait la même chose pour des meubles : « il a changé le bureau/buffet/lit/sofa/… de côté. ».

Comment: de côté?? Tout dépend où elle est installée, cette fameuse télé.

Comment: @Lambie Si elle est installée le long d'un mur (puisqu'il est question d'en changer) elle est forcémment installée sur un côté de la pièce ; « mur » et « côté » sont matériellement interchangeables, s'il ne le sont pas du point de vue idiomaticité.

Comment: Il l'a changé de côté, elle est maintenant à la verticale ?

Comment: @NoëlloMiqueron Tu es taquin là... ;-) Pour moi, *changer de côté* est courant et bien compréhensible, *changer de mur* l'est beaucoup moins. S'il fallait garder *mur*, je dirais, *il l'a mise/placée sur un autre mur*.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, d'où mon point d'interrogation. Changer de mur si elle est accrochée au mur en effet mais ça ne semble pas être le cas. Je trouve changer de côté un peu inusité pour moi. Ok, « on va mettre la télé de ce bord-là de la pièce plutôt que de ce côté-là », mais j'ai besoin d'une référence à la _pièce_ pour que je trouve ça sans ambiguité. Je préfère _bord_ ou _le long du mur_ (opposé à celui de la fenêtre etc.). Je n'ai pas voté.

Comment: "de ce bord-la de la pièce"? Plutôt: On va mettre la télé de l'autre côte de la pièce. Par contre, l'autre côté de la pièce ne veut pas dire le mur. Accrocher ou fixer une télé au mur.

Comment: « Bord » ne convient pas en français métropolitain ; TLFi, **bord** : II.− P. anal. Extrémité délimitant une surface (suggérant notamment une image de creux). Une pièce n'a pas de bord. (le bord d'une feuille, mais pas le bord d'une pièce ; le bord d'une terrasse, d'une mezzanine, d'un toit, mais pas « le bord d'un grenier, d'une salle », etc.

Comment: C'est que JLF est assurément Canadien, comme moi d'ailleurs, d'où la différence. Donc oui dans une réponse qui se veut plus métropolitaine etc. etc. Mais à quoi ça va lui servir si cette rectitude devient impérialisme et rejette constamment ce qui est en usage dans son sociolecte. Je dis ça de même. La langue elle sert à communiquer avec ton monde.